# Extending the connection time limit in Oracle via SQL Developer?

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to dump the whole data from the developer db server to my local machine using SQL Developer, but whenever I try to export, the connection gets halted before I finish dumping/exporting.

Is there a way to adjust that db connection timeout?

Comment: If the database size is not trivial, any reason why you're not using the "proper" tools, i.e. expdp/impdp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no connection time limit imposed by SQL Developer.  If your connection is getting lost, that implies either that there is something in the network (a firewall for example) that limits the length of a connection or that there is something configured in the database (a profile, Resource Manager, etc.) that is causing the connection to be terminated.  Since you haven't told us what error you get, it is impossible to guess which of these options is the most likely source of your problem.

Of course, it would probably be more effective to use the proper tools (the DataPump version of the export and import utilities) for this sort of thing.

Comment: if am gonna use that datapump thing, will i be able to dump all the data?..because i asked other devs, i heard we all have the same time limit when connecting to a development db server

Comment: @sasori: you run expdp/impdp on the database server. There's no network connection involved unless you use dblinks.

Comment: @Mat , I don't have rights to install anything in the db server, all i can do as dev is connect and do some insert,update,delete  in the db/tables itself ...any other ideas what to do ?

Comment: @sasori - What is the source of the limit?  Is this a firewall issue?  A profile with a resource limit?  Something else?  DataPump is almost certainly already installed on the database server.